# Hardware based PWM fan solutions

Tags: pwm, fan, server

HPE DL360P’s love to run these fans (8x of them) at max speed. I don’t really need them all running, but wasn’t sure if dummy plugs to just trick the motherboard was a good idea. Wiring length and cable flexibility on the 6 pin connector is in short supply, so would that even be viable for a resistor?

Amateur to this and figured feedback wouldn’t go astray before I butcher a fan or two.
[image]
Part Number  732136-001
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue with my HP server. Problem is that it sets a target RPM and adjust duty cycle until the tachometer matches, so no passive solution possible without a fan error message. I will make an MCU-adapter in-line to simple read and upscale the tachometer pulse to make it quiet, possibly with offset, if I could only find the time for it. Just don’t ask about it on superuser…

Comment: While using the custom ILO firmware mostly works, I was hoping to be a bit more aggresive (Also it's easier to not set fan speeds every hard boot).

Is there no 'passive' option in the sense that I can't just have something saying "The fans are on 100%" via a stub? Not having fans is probably the best option for 6 connectors.

Comment: Not that I can think of since the regulation loop is done on the MB or in software. It would however not take many lines of code in a small MCU to insert in series and cheat the signal.

Comment: After some digging, it seems you may just be able to bridge pins 1,2,4,6 and make a cheap stub. 

Going to try, will report back.